# when will GoogleMLKit support arm64 simulator

Tags: ios, google-mlkit

We're using GoogleMLKit on iOS, and right now our team is switching to m1 Macbook.
We have to set some conditions to make it work on ios-arm64-simulator like this

[image]

I'd like to know if google official has a plan to support ios-arm64-simulator
such as providing an xcframework?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we have a plan, but it can take some time to find a solution.

Comment: Is there any issue open we can track progress on this topic?

Comment: Yes, here is the open issue link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178965151

Comment: @DongChen it's been 2 years and we never heard back from Google, it's still missing the arm64...